# Vue JS, Modal Window through components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to make the modal visible on click, I work through components, new Vue constructs do not work
I've never worked with Vue, now I'm asking for help
Error:
64:4  error  'showModal:' is defined but never used  no-unused-labels

```
<template>
<modalPhoto v-if="showModal == 'true'"></modalPhoto>
<div class="block-inputs">
    <div class="input-header">
        <h3>Photos</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="photos">
        <div class="photo-block">
            <img src="../assets/photo.jpg" class="photo modal-img" v-on:click="viewPhoto('true')">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="save-changes">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <button class="button-add button-save">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import modalPhoto from './modal/modalPhoto.vue';

export default {
    name: 'Photos',
    data() {
        showModal: false
    },
    methods: {
        viewPhoto() {
            this.showModal = true;
        }
    },
    components: {
        modalPhoto,
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the single quotes in the template showModal == 'true' and viewPhoto('true')
by the way you don't need the fonction you can do v-on:click="showModal = true"

Comment: or use <modalPhoto v-if="showModal"></modalPhoto>